# Facebook app notifications error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am getting error while sending app notification using open graph api explorer, error information is as follows

{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 15
  }
}

can any one tell me how to solve this issue as i have try different combination for app setting but nothing works.

Comment: The error is pretty straight forward, use your APP access token. If you need more help then this - post your code!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/